# Install Snow Leopard Server on a Virtual Machine on a Mac Mini Server

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have a working Mac Mini Server with Snow Leopard.

I want to upgrade it to Lion, but there's some critical legacy software that doesn't work on Lion, so I figured I'd install a copy of the same server in a Virtual Box (using the install DVD).

Problem: Mac Mini Server doesn't have an optical drive -- and it fails to install from a ripped DMG of the DVD (created on a MacBook).

What can I do? Is this supposed to work (VirtualBox does claim to support a "64 bit Mac Server" guest).

Comment: I'd say (personal preference) the easiest way would be to use an external USB optical drive.  In my opinion, purchasing one would make sense for other uses, especially for burning DVD's, ripping other files, etc.  If you don't want to purchase one maybe you can borrow one from a friend/family member?

Comment: Did you do a hash check with the DMG? Maybe it got corrupted in the progress because I did that in the past before and it worked fine.